# Making Cell as Non-Editable in HandsonTable

Tags: handsontable

1. How to make a cell in Handsontable non-editable?
2. I have a column in handsontable as custome render type in which I'm invoking javascript function with parameter.

I guess this might lead to security issue which means dispDetails functions can be invoked with passing invalid values. How to avoid the above stated risk?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the cell options: https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/wiki/Options#cell-options

The "readOnly" option might what you are looking for.

There is also a settings which needs to be used as well called:

"disableVisualSelection"

This needs to be applied to the table itself.

Comment: Hi d.h.  Thanks for your response.  As per guide, cell option might create performance issue. Is there any alternative?  Also I have a requirement to make particular row as readonly?       Another question on disableVisualSelection - How to use this property?  I tried to set at table definition level. It didnt work.

Comment: How is this a performance issue? How big is your table? With the celloptions you can specify which cells are readonly. So if you are planning to set specific rows as readonly that is going to work with the celloptions.

Comment: Here is the docu for the Option: http://docs.handsontable.com/0.15.0-beta6/Options.html#disableVisualSelection